# "Invalid configuration mapping" in visual studio mac

Tags: visual-studio, monogame

I'm trying to use Monogame on a mac. All of the installation instructions are on Xamarin Studio, which to my knowledge, no longer exists as it was integrated into Visual Studio. I found that Monogame *technically* works with Visual Studio 2017 (Getting the 2017 version was an adventure in and of itself, as MonoGame didn't work with the 2019 version), however whenever I create a new project the (Project Name).Desktop folder has a red X mark beside it. when I hover over it, it says "Invalid Configuration Mapping." The strangest part is, when I build and run the project, I get no errors whatsoever. I still don't get my beautiful light blue window though.

I also tried doing a MonoMac application, but it doesn't understand the Game class. How can I get Monogame working on my mac?

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, review: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/configurations?view=vsmac-2019

Under Solution / Configuration you'll see the problem, change the dropdown options to match the configuration file you have and the red cross will be removed.

Comment: More specifically (for my case at lease), navigate to: Solution Options > Build > Configurations > Configuration Mappings.

Double click on the invalid configuration in the list and choose one of the options listed.

Comment: The approach described by Harlan doesn't seem possible for Visual Studio on macOS, but the approach described by Access Denied works fine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76741209/250164

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this weird error. Solution was to remove project from solution and readd it to the solution as existing. sln file contained some old configuration info and this is what error says that there are some problems with sln file.

Comment: I think this is the easiest approach. It will probably do some stuff behind the scenes to fix configuration mappings. Don't need to manually figure it out.